# Access param from app.use in controller

Tags: express

I want to access a param defined in my app.use (`index.js`) inside my app.get (`idCtrl.js`). Below I have an boiled down version of my code. The route works and sends me to the controller for a url such as `/1234` but I can't access `:id` from `req.params`.

## index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var idCtrl  = require('./idCtrl');
...
app.use('/:id([0-9]{4})', idCtrl);
```

## idCtrl.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
...
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  // I wanna access :id from the app.use in index.js
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle that situation is

First, set up your param

```
router.param('id',function(req,res,next,id)
{
     //d owhatever you want with your param here
     req.paramID = id; // save it in your req
     next(); // Continue to your get('/:id')
};
```

Then, set up the route using the param

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res){
      console.log(req.paramID); // You got your param here
});
```

Comment: So I'd leave my `index.js` code as is, and just modify the `idCtrl.js` file?

Comment: app.use('/:id([0-9]{4})', idCtrl); should be app.use('/',idCtrl); the rest is okay